# Button don't redirect using onClick - Javascript HTML

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

i'm working in a simple web, and i use a botton for enter to the principal page, but nothing happens, only work if i don't use the function, see:

With this don´t work:

The button:

```
<center><input type="button" name="Entrar" onClick="iniciar()" value=" Ingresar " >
```

The function "iniciar()":

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function iniciar(){
var value
var clase,nombre,validate="ATS1"
    nombre=window.prompt("Digite su primer nombre");
    clase=prompt("Digite su codigo de seccion de clase (letras en mayuscula)");

    if (clase==validate){
        value = 3;
    }
    else{
        value = 0;
    }

if (value == 3){
    window.alert("Ingreso exitoso, presione Aceptar.")
    var pag="formulario.html"   

    alert("Aceptado \nPulse Aceptar y sera redireccionado en 2 segundos.", setTimeout("location.href=pag",2000))    
     //Dos segundos para redireccionar
}
else{
    alert("Lo sentimos mucho, usted no tiene acceso a la pagina. Usted pertenece a otro curso, adios.")
    close()}
}

</script>
```

But if i don't use the button, i use the script of java directly (no function) in the page this is working (redirect)

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

var value
var clase,nombre,validate="ATS1"
    nombre=window.prompt("Digite su primer nombre");
    clase=prompt("Digite su codigo de seccion de clase (letras en mayuscula)");

    if (clase==validate){
        value = 3;
    }
    else{
        value = 0;
    }

if (value == 3){
    window.alert("Ingreso exitoso, presione Aceptar.")
    var pag="formulario.html"   

    alert("Aceptado \nPulse Aceptar y sera redireccionado en 2 segundos.", setTimeout("location.href=pag",2000))    
     //Dos segundos para redireccionar
}
else{
    alert("Lo sentimos mucho, usted no tiene acceso a la pagina. Usted pertenece a otro curso, adios.")
    close()}


</script>
```

I hope that they can understand me :/
Thanks

=================================================================

See all the code (i use the syntax that @Moogs send me it's work :D):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Formulario</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function cerrar(){
    close()
}

function iniciar(){
var value
var clase,nombre,validate="ATS1"
    nombre=window.prompt("Digite su primer nombre");
    clase=prompt("Digite su codigo de seccion de clase (letras en mayuscula)");

    if (clase==validate){
        value = 3;
    }
    else{
        value = 0;
    }

if (value == 3){
    window.alert("Ingreso exitoso, presione Aceptar.")
    var pag="formulario.html"   

    alert("Aceptado \nPulse Aceptar y sera redireccionado en 2 segundos.");
    setTimeout(function() {
             window.location.href = pag;
        }, 2000)    
     //Dos segundos para redireccionar
}
else{
    alert("Lo sentimos mucho, usted no tiene acceso a la pagina. Usted pertenece a otro curso, adios.")
    close()}
}
document.querySelector('[type="button"]').onclick = iniciar;
</script>
</head>

<body>

<center><font face="Lucida handwriting"><h1><b><i>Formulario</i></b></h1></font></center><hr>
<br>
<center><input type="button" name="Entrar" onClick="iniciar()" value=" Ingresar ">
<input type="button" name="Salir" onClick="cerrar()" value=" Salir ">
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I speak spanish, sorry if my english is bad .-. :3

Comment: `clase=prompt(` should be `clase=window.prompt(` not sure if it fixes it... You say it does not redirect, but nothing redirects in your code! When you use button click, does it ask you the two questions and does it alert something?

Comment: @Salketer prompt is bound to the window object so "window.prompt" is the same as "prompt" because it's global. It makes no difference

Comment: in your case when trying execute timeout func, js tried found `pag` variable, so timeout callback call in global scope, but your `pag` - local variable, so you have `Uncaught ReferenceError: pag is not defined`. You can make it global, or better use function instead string in _setTimeout_

Comment: also second sample working because you define all variables in global scope

Comment: from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout): _using this syntax is not recommended_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function for the setTimeout callback instead of an eval string and place the timeout after the alert instead of as an alert argument.

```js
function iniciar() {
    var value = 0;
    var clase;
    var nombre;
    var validate = "ATS1";
    
    nombre = prompt("Digite su primer nombre");
    clase = prompt("Digite su codigo de seccion de clase (letras en mayuscula)");

    if (clase === validate) {
        value = 3;
    }

    if (value == 3) {
        alert("Ingreso exitoso, presione Aceptar.");
        
        var pag = "formulario.html"

        alert("Aceptado \nPulse Aceptar y sera redireccionado en 2 segundos.");
        setTimeout(function() {
             alert('redirect');
             window.location.href = pag;
        }, 2000)
    } else {
        alert("Lo sentimos mucho, usted no tiene acceso a la pagina. Usted pertenece a otro curso, adios.");
        close();
    }
}

document.querySelector('[type="button"]').onclick = iniciar;
```

```html
<input type="button" name="Entrar" value=" Ingresar " >
```

Comment: i add all the code, using your syntax and don't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Here i use your code it's working fine:

Check it:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<style>
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function iniciar(){
alert("hello");
var value
var clase,nombre,validate="ATS1"
    nombre=window.prompt("Digite su primer nombre");
    clase=prompt("Digite su codigo de seccion de clase (letras en mayuscula)");

    if (clase==validate){
        value = 3;
    }
    else{
        value = 0;
    }

if (value == 3){
    window.alert("Ingreso exitoso, presione Aceptar.")
    var pag="formulario.html"   

    alert("Aceptado \nPulse Aceptar y sera redireccionado en 2 segundos.", setTimeout("location.href=pag",2000))    
     //Dos segundos para redireccionar
}
else{
    alert("Lo sentimos mucho, usted no tiene acceso a la pagina. Usted pertenece a otro curso, adios.")
    close()}
}

</script>
 <center><input type="button" name="Entrar" onClick="iniciar()" value=" Ingresar " >
</body>
</html>
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3hxsmzu/) here.